Quark strings/gluon flux tubes connecting quarks - what are their properties? Are they topological vortices?
In QCD there are often used 1D objects connecting quarks, also said to be the original inspiration for string theory, referred as quark strings or gluon flux tube - are they the same?
Asking for their (non-perturbative) field configurations, I have only found these superconductor-like models with Abrikosov-like topological vortices (e.g. https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.88.054504 ) - can we say all of them are topological vortices?
If so, what if they enclose into a loop - forming something very light and stable - does it correspond to some particle like gluon or neutrino?
Are they ending in quarks or continue further? Are they Y-shaped in baryons like in http://backreaction.blogspot.com/2017/12/get-your-protons-right.html ? If so, how topological vortices could form Y-shape connection?
Also string hadronization popular to model LHC collisions uses strings - are they the same? Can we imagine hadronization as decay of high energy topological vortex?
Some images based on https://indico.cern.ch/event/1252547/contributions/5440963/attachments/2661340/4610500/CERN-23.pdf :


An impossibly broad question. Rewrite less discursively.

These are related questions with various answers in literature - maybe just brief answers to order the mainstream view on this crucial but looking unordered topic.

Please ask one question at a time.

So I have emphasized the central most important question: are they topological vortices? (deeply connected with the remaining questions: if so, what if it closes into a loop? how it could be Y-shape in baryon? LHC string hadronization is indeed decay of topological vortex?)

You are not happy with this review?

Thanks, I see it is 40 years old - I have seen various answers in literature, wanted to ask how modern mainstream sees such looking basic questions?

They are touchy-feely models, not basic questions. You can follow the groaning 60-year-old literature.

These are basic questions about baryon structure, what are strings in popular "string hadronization" ... asking about nonperturbative picture - the closest seems lattice QCD, which is relatively recent - does it/should it include 1D quark string structures stabilized by topology?
